# What is Meant by "Change of Origin" in Coordinate Geometry?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, transformation, change-of-variable

I don't think I understand what is meant by "to shift the origin of coordinates to the point $(h,k)$ in coordinate geometry. I've read Loney's book on coordinate geometry in which he says that to shift the origin of coordinates that a curve is referred by, you must replace $x$ with $x + h$ and $y$ by $y + k$. Also, in some online examples I seem to be utterly puzzled. Here's an example I found on unacademy.com:

Example 1: Find the new equation of the following curve after the coordinates are transformed: $x + 3y = 6$, when the origin is transferred to the unique point $(–4, 1)$.

they replace $x$ with $x-4$ and $y$ with $y + 1$ to get $x + 3y = 7$. However, using an  online graphing calculator, I can see that it has actually been shifted to $(4,-1)$. Hence, I think I misunderstand what is meant by "shift of origin". the original graph $x + 3y = 6$ was two units up the y-axis from the original origin, hence the new graph $x + 3y = 7$ should also be two units up the y-axis from the new origin, however it is not. Could someone please help me, I am really stuck and cannot further explore the subject. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "the original graph $x+3y=6$ was two units up the y-axis from the original origin, hence the new graph $x+3y=7$ should also be two units up the y-axis from the new origin" Why should it be? If the line stayed in the same relation to the new origin, how is that moving the origin?

Comment: I'd advise that you draw the starting line in coordinate plane, then draw lines parallel to the axes through the new origin $(-4,1)$. Mark the unit distance on the new axes to be the same length as the original one. Now try to write equation of the starting line according to these new axes. What is the equation?

Comment: @Ennar a thousand and one thanks to you! I now see exactly where I was oblivious. To state exactly what I thought: I thought that "change in origin" meant to "take" the curve and move it so that it has the same relation to the new origin as it had to the old one. What was actually meant by "change of origin" was to REWRITE the curve through the perspective of the new origin. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: You are correct, I'm glad you understood it :)

Comment: It might also be helpful to write $x = x' -4$ and $y = y'+1$ to understand the difference between two coordinate systems. To see that this is correct, think of the point $A(-4,1)$ in the old coordinates, set $x=-4$, $y = 1$ to get $x' = 0$, $y' = 0$, so $A$ now has coordinates $(0,0)$.